# What does it mean "to make the numbers work"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Everyone is asking why. It's simple, really. We are the network's
>   golden child in every way, except profit margins. Fact is, #Eureka is
>   an expensive show to make. And we could not maintain the quality of
>   our show with the cuts it would take to make us profitable for Syfy's
>   new parent company. Our creative execs at Syfy fought hard to keep us.
>   Trust me, they LOVE us. We just couldn't **make the numbers work**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(U.S._TV_series)

How could one explain what does it mean *to make the numbers work*?

Answer (score 6):

*Numbers* here is a colloquialism that refers to the profit versus expenses or loss in a business or other endeavor.  The idea comes from accounting spreadsheets or budgeting charts, where each expense or income is listed on a line along with its value.

To *make the numbers work* means to make sure expenses are covered by income and that this is reflected to investors.  It can be a euphemism for falsifying financial reports or doing illicit things to acquire money/resources.

An implication with saying "couldn't make the numbers work" is that an undertaking was liked and desirable, but money ran out.

Answer (score 3):

**Make the numbers work** is an idiom used to describe a math problem where the **answer and inputs are known**, however the calculation necessary to achieve the answer is not know (*the* work), so there is a **search for the calculation** to try to make the numbers work.

For example you want to buy a new car, but you only have $100.
Well, it's impossible because **the numbers don't work**.
It is not possible to buy a new car with only $100.

A similar phrase is

> **get the numbers to add up**
>   *I can't get the numbers to add up*
>   *I can't make the numbers work*

This should not be confused with

> **it doesn't add up**

which means *something* doesn't make any sense.